# authorize and capture functions are not firing magento custom payment gateway

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I've created a custom payment gateway, but my capture and authorize functions are not firing when I try to place order. I am not sue what is missing here. Here is my payment model code:

```
class RD_Echeck_Model_Paymentmethod extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract {
    protected $_code  = 'echeck';
    protected $_formBlockType = 'echeck/form_echeck';
    protected $_infoBlockType = 'echeck/info_echeck';
    protected $_canAuthorize = true;
    protected $_canCapture = true;
    protected $_canRefund = false;


public function authorize(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
{
    echo 'sa';die;
    Mage::log('** Capturing **');
    // Third-party API stuff would go here, with exceptions being thrown if the gateway determines they've provided an invalid card, etc.
}

public function capture(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
{
    echo 'sa';die;
    Mage::log('** Capturing **');
    // Third-party API stuff would go here, with exceptions being thrown if the gateway determines they've provided an invalid card, etc.
}

}
```

My XML payment configuration:

```
  <default>
    <payment>
      <echeck>
        <active>1</active>
        <model>echeck/paymentmethod</model>
        <order_status>pending</order_status>
        <title>TheEcheck</title>
        <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
        <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
      </echeck>
    </payment>
  </default>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my configuration file and everything seems fine now. I've just added payment_action as authorize.

```
  <default>
    <payment>
      <echeck>
        <active>1</active>
        <model>echeck/echeck</model>
        <order_status>processing</order_status>
        <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
        <title>TheEcheck</title>
        <currency>USD</currency>
        <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
      </echeck>
    </payment>
  </default>
```